# Powershell add type in class in PSM1

Tags: powershell, add-type

In a PS1, this works

```
class pxInitFailureMessage {
    static [void] Send ([int32]$processID, [String]$title, [string]$message) {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName:System.Windows.Forms
        Add-Type -AssemblyName:System.Drawing
        $balloonTip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $balloonTip.icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($(Get-Process -id:$processID | Select-Object -expandProperty:Path))
        $balloonTip.balloonTipIcon = 'Error'
        $balloonTip.balloonTipTitle = $title
        $balloonTip.balloonTipText = $message
        $balloonTip.visible = $true 
        $balloonTip.ShowBalloonTip(0)
        $balloonTip.Dispose
    }
}
[pxInitFailureMessage]::Send($pid, 'Title', 'Message is just some extra text')
```

But, move that class to a library.PSM1 file, and this in the PS1

```
Using module '\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 4.#\Dev 4.0\#Spikes\Windows7\library.psm1'
[pxInitFailureMessage]::Send($pid, 'Title', 'Message is just some extra text')
```

And it works in the ISE, but not in the console when run from a shortcut. I get `Unable to find type [system.drawing.icon].`

Obviously the first Add-Type works, I get no error at New-Object. So why is the second type load failing? I also tried moving the two Add-Type lines out of the class, and into the root of the module file, with the same results. What DOES work is adding those lines to the PS1, between `using module` (which has to be the first non remarked line) and the call. That works, but then you don't have a self contained class, which seems to suck a bit. What am I misunderstanding here?

How does one make a self contained class that uses .NET types and work with it from  a module file?

Comment: Have you checked the MSDN Library? https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest?view=powershell-5.1 ? Particulary the -RequiredAssemblies part handles your issue

Comment: @user3898488 Based on that I tried `Get-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics -List | Format-List -Property *` and it returned the expected information. But `Get-Module System.Drawing.Icon -List | Format-List -Property *` & `Get-Module System.Drawing -List | Format-List -Property *` return nothing at all. That said, I expect this will be.a useful link as I dig deeper into .NET via PS. So woot!

Comment: i can take a look into this later if noone knows the answer

Comment: It works in the ISE because required assemblies are already loaded. Pasting the class definition into the normal PS console throws the the same error (without actually using the class, just the class definition alone throws the error). In ohter words, it's not a problem of ps1/psm1.

`I also tried moving the two Add-Type lines out of the class, and into the root of the module file, with the same result` When commands include `class`, PowerShell first evaluates(parses) them. So you need to first load assemblies in some way...

Comment: Yeah, I realize now the fundamental problem is I am asking my class to go outside itself, and the module file that holds it, to get icon information about a totally different process. Dumb. If I assign the icon to a variable, in the main script, where it belongs, and pass THAT to the class, everything works as it should, and having `using assembly System.Drawing` makes sense, because that's where I need and use it. So, even if my original approach had worked, it still would have been a poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the solution I came up with is as follows. In library.PSM1 I have...

```
class pxInitFailureMessage {
    static [void] Send ([int32]$processID, [String]$title, [string]$message, [System.Drawing.Icon]$icon) {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName:System.Windows.Forms
        $balloonTip = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
        $balloonTip.icon = $icon
        $balloonTip.balloonTipIcon = 'Error'
        $balloonTip.balloonTipTitle = $title
        $balloonTip.balloonTipText = $message
        $balloonTip.visible = $true 
        $balloonTip.ShowBalloonTip(0)
        $balloonTip.Dispose
    }
}
```

And in my scrip I have...

```
using assembly System.Drawing
Using module '.\library.psm1'

$processIcon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($(Get-Process -id:$pID | Select-Object -expandProperty:Path))

[pxInitFailureMessage]::Send($pid, 'Title', 'Message is just some extra text', $processIcon)
```

The key is that the class IS now self contained, and follows good practice of providing the class with everything it needs, so it doesn't have to go looking outside itself. I could just as easily use my own ICO file for the icon, like so...

```
$processIcon = [system.drawing.icon]::New('\\Mac\iCloud Drive\Px Tools 4.#\Dev 4.0\Px_Resources\PxIcon.ico')
```

Again with a literal path in this example.

So, I learned a thing today. Woot.